# How does Laravel compile Blade directives into PHP?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Using the `Blade::render(string $string, array $data = [], bool $deleteCachedView = false)` method to compile blade templates from strings creates two views with hashed names. The first view is an exact copy of the `$string` parameter. The second one has converted the blade directives into PHP.

So this:

```
@if ($name === 'Foo') Hello, {{ $name }}! @else Hello, bar! @endif
```

Becomes this:

```
<?php if($name === 'Foo'): ?> Hello, <?php echo e($name); ?>! <?php else: ?> Hello, bar! <?php endif; ?>
```

My question is, where does the compilation into PHP actually happen? How is that second file produced? I can't for the life of me find it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the file in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php

Hope that can help you :)

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this file. For example, it uses the `Concerns\CompilesConditionals` trait, but that trait's methods aren't used anywhere else in the code base. Do you have any insight?

Comment: @qotsa42 those methods do get called ... `compileAuth` is what `@auth` gets replaced with ... it is indirect and the calls are dynamic so you won't see those method names being called explicitly in the code (`$method = 'compile'.ucfirst($match[1])`)